# AndroidStudio　エラー：Unable to locate adb within SDK

Tags: android, java, android-studio

AndroidStudioで実機でインストールをしたいのですが、実行ボタンを押すと、Unable to locate adb within SDKとメッセージが出ます。
よくわからないので解決方法をお願いします

Answer (score 2):

エラーの内容は、SDK内のadbというプログラムが見つからないというものです。

[adb（Android Debug Bridge）](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/help/adb.html)は、AndoridデバイスとPCを接続して、ビルドしたアプリケーションを転送するなどの役割を果たしています。詳細についてはリンク先を参照してください。

SDKマネージャを開いて`Android SDK Platform-tools`がインストールされているかどうか、インストール済みであれば再インストールを試してみてください。何らかの理由で環境の一部がおかしくなってしまっているのであれば、Android SDK自体を再インストールするのが確実だと思います。